# What types of operations are permitted inside tf.cond

Tags: tensorflow

It seems that `tf.cond(cond, fn1, fn2)` executes possible dependencies for both branches, so any computation we would like to perform if and only if the conditions hold have to be put into the function fn1 fn2.

However I am confused as to what fn actually is. Every variable/op in tensorflow should be a node of the computation graph, but fn is actually a python function. This leads to many questions. For example, is this function re-evaluated every time `sess.run` is executed? Can this function return different computation graphs each time? Can placeholders be defined in them, and if not how to avoid supplying values to placeholders we know will not be used when, for example, there is a switch variable that chooses between different inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions passed to `tf.cond` are only run when the op is defined, not during graph execution. And [both of them are run](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L1760), exactly once as far as I can see. The functions themselves are just a way to indicate exactly which ops should have the conditional execution behavior: note the `context_t.Enter()`/`context_t.Exit()` calls surrounding each function call.

Hopefully that clarifies things. The functions are a useful way of grouping ops during graph definition. There's no function execution magic going on in the TensorFlow graph.